# Increase size of IntelliJ select run configuration dialog

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, dialog

Is there a way to increase the size of the IntelliJ dialog that allows you to select a run configuration?  The corners aren't draggable.  I'm often "flying blind" because all that's visible is the package name, as you can see from the image:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The size can be changes in the Intellij registry:

1. Open the registry by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
2. Find the item 'run.configuration.max.name.lenght'
3. Change it's value

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this for some reason. You could edit the configs to use a shorter name. I don't know why your names seem to have the package name in them. Configs on my system just use the class name which makes them shorter.

Alternatively if you select Edit Configurations then you'll be able to see the full name and run them. You should be able to bind this to a key stroke to make it a bit more convenient.